# Why Is The Spinner Touch Event Firing The Ripple On Another Spinner On Nougat (API 24 and Up)?

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner, android-7.0-nougat

I am having an issue with Spinners in Android and I am looking for help.

I have a TableLayout that has multiple Spinners. Each of these are backed by individual adapters that display a "SELECT" hint if there is more than one option available for that Spinner, otherwise we are supposed to hide the caret and disable the Spinner. The Spinners are linked, where the top Spinner (parent) selection populates the bottom Spinner (child). This seems to be working fine in terms of selections. However, the issue I am experiencing is after I have made my selection, any subsequent touch event of the ***parent*** Spinner will fire the ripple on the ***child*** Spinner and **NOT** the one you just touched. This seems to only happen on Nougat though. I can't reproduce this on API 23 and lower.

Here are some images for reference:

**Landing View:**

[image: Landing View]

**Parent Selection:**

[image: Parent Selection]

Now this is the part where the issue happens. Whenever I just click the parent Spinner, the child spinner's caret ripple effect is fired (I don't even have to actually select an option in the parent):

[image: Ripple Effect On Child Spinner]

Here is my layout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:showDividers="middle|end"
android:stretchColumns="1">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/id_table_row_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ID"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <my.widget.MySpinner
        android:id="@+id/id_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="end" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/name_table_row_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <my.widget.MySpinner
        android:id="@+id/name_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="end" />
</TableRow>
```

It's important to note that I store the drawable for the parent selection when the UI is generated for use later on when I check if I should show/hide the caret for each spinner (if items == 1, then disable caret, otherwise enable it). Here is the code to show/hide the Spinner:

**Enable Spinner:**

```
    // Show the arrow
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 23)
    {
        spinner.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }
    else
    {
        spinner.setBackground(this.mDefaultSpinnerDrawable);
    }
    spinner.setEnabled(true);
```

**Disable Spinner:**

```
    // Hide the arrow
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 23 )
    {
        spinner.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    }
    else
    {
        spinner.setBackground(null);
    }
    spinner.setEnabled(false);
```

The "default" drawable is stored when the parent adapter is created:

```
    // Save the default background
    mDefaultSpinnerDrawable = mIdSpinner.getBackground();
```

It's important to note that the child adapter(s) are created in the onItemSelected event of its "**parent**" Spinner:

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            mNameSpinner.setAdapter(null);

            MyDto selectedIdDto = (MyDto ) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            List<NameDto> selectedNameDtos = selectedIdDto.getNameList();

            mNameSpinnerAdapter = new NameArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.content_search_spinner_item, selectedNameDtos);
            mNameSpinner.setAdapter(mNameSpinnerAdapter);

            if (selectedNameDtos.size() == 1)
            {
                disableSpinner(mNameSpinner);
            }
            else
            {
                enableSpinner(mNameSpinner);
                mNameSpinner.setSelection(mNameSpinnerAdapter.getHintIndex());

            }
        }
```

I am confused as to how this is a problem in API 24 and can't be reproduced in earlier versions (we are targeting API >=21). Does anyone have any ideas where I have gone wrong?

**UPDATE:**
It looks like setting the "default" drawable is the culprit. It appears that even though I am setting the background to each individual spinner, the drawable is shared amongst all of them? I verified this by adding a different colour background to each individual spinner and noticed that when I ran the app on the emulator, they all were coloured the same. If I comment out the code to the remove and set the background (in enable and disable methods described above) each individual spinner shows it's specific colour.... HOWEVER, the caret will always appear which is a problem. Has anyone successfully implemented the showing and hiding of the Spinner caret?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
spinner.setBackground(this.mDefaultSpinnerDrawable);
```

Do:

```
spinner.setBackground(this.mDefaultSpinnerDrawable.mutate());
```